# Select default option in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a simple select dropdown which should be having a default option selected. I tried using ngValue, selected, [selected]="true" but none of them work.

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="keyType"> 
<option [ngValue]="'Numeric'" selected>Numeric</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'Random'">Random</option>
</select>
```

It shows as blank initially, but when I choose any option, there's no blank option anymore. I can't make changes on the TS side, because keytype is always '', unless a certain condition is met.

Stackblitz link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhtkiv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: <option></option> does providing an empty option in html , causes any problem to your requirement?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suxlrd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @AmpatiHareesh, no, but I don't see the point of doing it.

Comment: Initially it shows empty , because keyType does not have any value in it, once after the selection, keyType equals Numeric/Random..and here you are not providing the empty value, so that keyType goes to '' ,That's the reason you can't see the empty value once after the selection

Comment: @Aijaz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5fvxy

Answer (score 0):

[Here is your blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdw1ic?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

You have to set the value of your `ngModel` to the corresponding option you want selected.

And blank values need to be explicitly written as an option, otherwise they disappear once you chose a value. That's not Angular, that's HTML standards.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do that on the TS side because the object is different when its rendered.

Comment: I'm sorry what ?

Comment: Sorry. The select dropdown initializes with a lot of ngif statements, and keytype is always set to ''. Only when the ngif statement which shows this current dropdown, I want to set keytype to numeric, or else I have to keep it as blank.

Comment: Then set the value of your select according to your conditions, what's the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the binding like this, no need for selected and ngValue

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    keyType: any;
    items = ['Numeric', 'Random']

    ngOnInit(){
        this.keyType = this.items[0];
    }
}
```

And for the html

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="keyType">
<option *ngFor="let i of items" [value]="i">{{i}}</option>  
</select>

{{keyType}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> One way of doing is by providing default option with empty value

Here is the modified stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suxlrd?file=src/app/app.component.html